# Stack Exchange Dump 2 MySQL - Load the data dump into a database with Python

Tags: app, python, data-dump

I created a a utility to load the Stack Exchange data dump into a MySQL database:

#### https://github.com/stephenostermiller/stack-exchange-2-mysql

It is written in Python so it should in theory work on multiple platforms, however I have only tested it on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS with MySQL 8.0.29.

#### Requirements

- Python 3
- Python 3 MySQL Connector
- MySQL (tested against version 8)
- P7zip command line tool
- About 300 GB of disk space
- A downloaded data dump

#### Capabilities

- Load part or all of the data dump
- Creates and maintains the database schema